# Using middlewares to send email

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email, express

i want know if it is wrong create a Middleware to send an email before save the email in the database.

I have this schema:

```
{
  title: 'String',
  email: 'String'
  body: 'String'
}
```

And i already have the controller action, and is working fine. But before save the email in the MongoDB, i want send it with SendGrid, for this i'm making a Middleware:

```
app.post('/api/email', sendEmail, EmailController);
```

And i have all the logic to send using sendGrid in a function:

```
var sendEmail = function(request, response) {
 // logic
};
```

Is working perfectly, but i want know if is wrong, if is not a convention, if i should not use middleware for this kindle of stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware need `next` callback to start your `EmailController`

```
var sendEmail = function(request, response,next) {
 // do something
next()
};
```

Comment: I know, this is not relevant to the question.. i want know if is ok use middleware for that.

Comment: Use middleware here ok If you want to reuse this middleware. If you use once, you can set all logic inside EmailController ( use Promise for clear flow)